# Unhandled error event in packaging process

Tags: android, node.js, json

I'm very new to node JS, and This is my first "bigger" project, and the first project with android JS so the problem below probably is very usual, but I can't find any description about this, so please if you can help me.

I want to create an app, which I can save my GPS position and save it into a JSON file on the phone, and add some description for it.

1. I don't know how to test my app without exporting it into an apk and install it again and again.
2. I got `events.js: 183 throw er: //Unhandled 'error' event` while running `androidjs -b f` packaging command and I don't know how to solve it, what is this, as I think I handling every possible event. Here is my code about JSON handling, the rest of the program is just a client side `js` and `html`, so as I think if there is any problem than it is here somehow.

```
const back = require('androidjs').back;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// defin signal save-data to listen from front process

back.on('save-data', function(filepath, msg){
    /*fs.writeFile(path.join(filepath, 'data.json'), msg, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved')
    })*/
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
        if (err){
            var obj = {
                "positions": [
                    {coordinate: msg,
                    name: "Name",
                    desc: "Description"}
                ]
            };
            var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
            fs.writeFile('data.json', json, 'utf8', callback);
        } else {
        obj = JSON.parse(data); //now it an object
        obj.positions.push({oordinate: msg,
                            name: "Name",
                            desc: "Description"}); //add some data
        json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
        fs.writeFile('data.json', json, 'utf8', callback); // write it back 
    }});
})

back.on('get-data', function(filepath){
    /*fs.readFile(path.join(filepath, 'data.json'), 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        if(err) back.send('get-data-result', '@@');
        else back.send('get-data-result', data);
    })*/
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
    //let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);

    back.send('get-data-result', rawdata);
})

back.on('error', function (error) {
    back.send('printerror', error);
})
```

I have added this on each front side:

```
              fron.on('printerror', function(error){
                document.write('<div class="callout alert"> <h5>ERROR!</h5><p>' + error);
                document.write('</p></div>');
              })
```

Comment: add back.on('error', function (error) {// handle error and debug what is error})

Comment: @RahulKumar I updated my code as you suggested (see above), but the same error msg appear again.